# Scrapy Deltafetch incremental crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on Scrapy to scrap the website. And I want to extract only those items which have not been scraped in its previous run.
I am trying it on "https://www.ndtv.com/top-stories" website to extract only 1st headline if it is updated.

Below is my code:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from w3lib.url import url_query_parameter

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"

    start_urls = [
       'https://www.ndtv.com/top-stories',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
       print ('testing')
       print(response.url)

       yield {
            'heading': response.css('div.nstory_header    a::text').extract_first(),

        }
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_crawl_once.CrawlOnceMiddleware': 100,
}
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    #'inc_crawling.middlewares.IncCrawlingSpiderMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.referer.RefererMiddleware': True,
    'scrapy_deltafetch.DeltaFetch': 100,
    'scrapy_crawl_once.CrawlOnceMiddleware': 100,
    'scrapylib.deltafetch.DeltaFetch': 100,
    'inc_crawling.middlewares.deltafetch.DeltaFetch': 100,
}
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
COOKIES_DEBUG = True
DELTAFETCH_ENABLED = True
DELTAFETCH_DIR = '/home/administrator/apps/inc_crawling'
DOTSCRAPY_ENABLED = True
```

I have updated above code in setting.py file:

I am running the above code using "scrapy crawl test -o test.json" command and after each run .db file and test.json file gets updated.

So, my expectation is whenever the 1st headline is updated only then .db gets updated.

kindly help me if there is any better approach to extract updated headline.

Comment: Is there any other way to for incremental crawling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a good way to implement this would be to override the [`DUPEFILTER_CLASS`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class) to check your database before doing the actual requests.

Scrapy uses a dupefilter class to avoid getting the same request twice, but it only works for running spiders.

Comment: If i  use "DUPEFILTER_CLASS" then it will not update  .db file even if headline is updated on UI. Because same URL create duplicate request.